# Problem receiving data from URL with a PHP script

Tags: php

I have a simple program with 5 radios. I would like to change the 'checked' radio from the URL. For example for **http://localhost:8080/radios.php?grade=4**, the radio 4 would be checked, and so on. And if there is no info in the URL, then no radios should be checked.

I currently tried to do this with a code like this, but it seems that the `$_GET['grade']` is not taking the info from the URL and therefore will always be null and no radios are checked.

```
<?php

$actualGrade = $_GET['grade'] ?? 0;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<?php foreach (range(1, 5) as $grade): ?>

    <input type="radio"
           name="grade"
           <?= $grade === $actualGrade ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
           value="<?= $grade ?>" />
    <?= $grade ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the mistake myself, in this line: <?= $grade === $actualGrade ? 'checked' : ''; ?> there should be double ==, not triple.

Comment: `$actualGrade` is a string, `$grade` is an integer. Since you used `===` instead of `==` it doesn't consider them equal.

Comment: You could also use `$actualGrade = intval($_GET['grade'] ?? 0)`